# How to spawn multiple instances of node.js on one machine to listen for different subdomains?

Tags: node.js

For subdomain like

```
a.abc.com    
b.abc.com    
c.abc.com
```

I would want to run the same duplicate of node.js script for them. I only have one machine unfortunately. Can somebody suggest how I may overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

if you have three "handlers", ie any function with a `(req, res)` signature, you can just do the following on a single server:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  switch (url.parse(req.url).hostname) {
    case 'a.abc.com':
      handlerA(req, res)
      break
    case 'b.abc.com':
      handlerB(req, res)
      break
    case 'c.abc.com':
      handlerC(req, res)
      break
    default:
      res.statusCode = 404
      res.end()
      break
  }
})
```

you don't *need* a reverse proxy unless you need every handler on its own process, ie if you have a LOT of load